# How can we find the exact data flow through all functions in Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, execution

I have a scenario where i need to find all the functions being executed in NodeJS project once we executed an API. Since my scenario is aws lamda is there any other package to find code flow which returns function names. I tried to use following but it doesn't fit for local lambda scenario

```
 npm install -g codeflow
```

Is there a recommendation for a module which does work in said environment?

Answer (score 1):

Create a decorator to log function names automatically during execution. You can also log times or other information.

**Basic example:**

```js
function functionDecorator(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(`Entering function: ${fn.name} Time: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
    const result = fn(...args);
    console.log(`Exiting function: ${fn.name} Time: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
    return result;
  };
}

exampleFunction = () => {
  console.log("Real function main")
};

const exampleFunctionDecorated = functionDecorator(exampleFunction);

exampleFunctionDecorated();
```